Power BI Incremental refresh change precision over time
I have a semantic model refreshed every day. In this semantic model, there's a table with a incremental refresh.
In SQL Management Studio, I can see the daily partitions, and when the month is complete, all the daily partitions are converted to a month partition (but containing all the daily datas).
What I am trying to do for 'old' data (3 months ago for exemple), is to replace the daily-grained data in the month partition with a month-grained data.
I would like to have it on the same table, not a different table, to simplify reports.
We do that for monitoring data like in prometheus, I was wondering if this is something we can also do in PowerBI.
